# Freelancer.com-like website but based only on BC payments using some sort of escrow-like system to make sure that employer has enough money?

Tags: job

Can a project similar to Freelancer.com or elance.com but based only on BC payments be created or the implementation of BC transfer between the employer and the freelancer would be too complicated?

I mean, i.e. freelancer.com is using escrow for transactions etc.

Is something silimar possible to develop but only for BC? If yes, is there some company that can do it like e.g. https://www.escrow.com/index.asp but with bitcoins?

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if Freelancer themselves simply offered to pay vendors with bitcoins and accepted bitcoins instead of feat?  They've already been asked: http://vimeo.com/29287295

Comment: Freelancer actually likes being needed for this process.  If Bitcoin makes is easier because hiring firm and freelance contractor both use the same currency, then why not just have the hiring firm pay directly and eliminate Freelancer.com?  So don't expect established firms like eLance, Freelancer, etc, to start using Bitcoins anytime soon.

Comment: Exactly, I don't think Freelancer would like to use BC in their business model. Anyway, I don't like Freelancer.com because they cut off is very big imo and I don't like their business model either.

Answer (score 2):

Such projects are possible with Bitcoins. Generally, what you can do with money, you can do with Bitcoins.

Escrow services in Bitcoin were popping up every now and then in the earlier days of Bitcoin, but I don't recall any of them becoming too popular. However, setting up an escrow-like service should be fairly simple. If you need some help, you can drop me a line ;).

Answer (score 0):

There is also http://bitlance.biz. From the functionality it looks quite similar to freelancer.com. As far as i know they use a classic escrow scheme but according to their FAQ they are working on the casascius escrow scheme.

Answer (score -1):

There is http://dogerr.com. It is a freelance marketplace where people can get hired for bit coin, litecoin and dogecoin. It's free to use.